# remove file extension with basename when using xargs

Tags: bash, xargs, basename

I would like to use xargs to run a command on a number of files where the output from the command has a different file extension. For the example below I am using `echo` as a dummy command.

`ls *.las | xargs -I % -n1 -P 10 echo $(basename % .las).ply`

this produces the output

```
ID1.las.ply
ID2.las.ply
ID3.las.ply
```

This does not strip the `.las` and only adds the new `.ply` file extension. What I would like is:

```
ID1.ply
ID2.ply
ID3.ply
```

Comment: the reason it doesn't work is that `$(basename % .las)` happens before `xargs` is run. It returns `%`. So xargs just sees `... echo %.ply`

Answer (score 2):

No need to use `ls | xargs`. Just do it in pure `bash` itself:

```bash
for i in *.las; do
   echo "${i%.las}.ply"
done
```

If you need to `ls | xargs` then use:

```bash
ls *.las | xargs -P 10 bash -c 'for f; do echo "${f%.las}".ply; done' _

ID1.ply
ID2.ply
ID4.ply
```

Comment: I would like to use `xargs` so I can run in parallel - `echo` is only a dummy command here, the actual process takes longer.

Comment: ok answer updated for `xargs`

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `sed`:

```bash
printf '%s\0' *.las | sed -z 's/las$/ply/' | xargs -0 -n 1 -P 10
```

Comment: depending on how many .las files the OP has the shell expansion may not work out as expected. the *.las may be very expensive for 10k+ files.

Comment: @AhmedMasud Fair point, but OP's using `ls *.las`, which is worse

Comment: yes both are bad but  yours is a little less ;)